# Laravel 5.2 - Email not sent in scheduled command

Tags: laravel-5, ovh

I need send an email some hours before an appointment occurs (so I need use CRON but it is off topic).

Usually in my controller I use an internal method of mine which uses `Mail::send($view, $data, ...)` and it works.

However when I call the same internal method from the command line via `php artisan my:command` which is registered in `kernel` I get :

```
[Swift_TransportException] 
Connection could not be established with host ssl0.ovh.net [Connection refused #111]
```

Please note that on my dev computer the above command runs smoothly and that it used to work (6 months ago according to the logs).

The project `.env` part concerning email consists in :

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=ssl0.ovh.net
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=myusername
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

So it seems `ssl0.ovh.net` cannot be called from command line. But how can I make the schedule command work ?

**Edit (solved):**

After reading some posts on the same topic and [this one specifically](http://community.ovh.com/t/symfony-swiftmailer-probleme-denvoi-demail-sites-heberges-ovh/501/2) it appears that `mail_driver` should be `mail` instead of `smtp`. I tried this before asking the question but it did not change anything.

Later while trying to change the `mail_host` without seeing any change on the behaviour, I cleared the config cache with `artisan config:clear`. And the changes started to be taken into account and the `mail` choice did worked.

**So the take-away if changing to `mail` does not work, is to try and clear the config cache**

Any help greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: The host maybe should be ip address

Comment: Thanks @MostafaHarb but I would prefer avoiding hard coding an IP address that could change. And the very same configuration works on my local dev machine and when called in the controller.

Comment: No i mean ssl0.ovh.net , the name os a translation of an ip, so it is constant that don't change, if the name change the ip will change so its the same thing, just replace the ip of server with name of server

Comment: I tried what `getent hosts` gave me (193.70.18.144) but it prevented any email to be sent from within the app. So I had to revert to ssl0.ovh.net.