# Guzzle ConnectException when running artisan command whereas it works fine in app

Tags: php, laravel, curl, laravel-artisan

In my Laravel 5.2 app running on php 7.2 on OVH shared-hosting I need to call a special URL on a remote server. So I use Guzzle like this (try .. catch omitted) :

```
 public static function doStuff() {
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

    $response = $client->request('GET', self::remote_address . $jsonFilenameId
        );

    $visit_ok = $response->getStatusCode() == "200";
 }
```

It works fine "from the running app" (I don't know how to call it), I mean when the user does something on my site, a controller's method invokes the above mentioned code, and the remote device gets the request.

Yet I wrote an artisan command and registered it, and when I call it with `php artisan my:registered_command` with the very same code, I get a `ConnectException` so the remote device is never called. Here is how it is called in the command :

```
use App\Http\Controllers\MyController;

class MyCommand extends Command {

 /**
 * The name and signature of the console command.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $signature = 'my:registered_command';


  /**
   * Execute the console command.
   *
   * @return mixed
   */
  public function handle() {
    MyController::doStuff();

  }
}
```

The error in log starts with:

```
 GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to re.mov.ed.ip port zzzz: Connection refused (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) in /home/.../vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php:200
```

*Please note : I doubt the issue comes from Guzzle because the same problem occurred previously with [sending email in the same conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61094796/laravel-5-2-email-not-sent-in-scheduled-command) (called from the command line).*

Also note that from my development machine the command is running fine, without throwing `ConnectException`.

Why do I get this `ConnectException` only when the method is called from the command line ? And what's the difference between calling an Guzzle from artisan and from the app ? Finally what should I do to work around this issue ?

**Edit : Printing phpinfo**

I added the following code to be able to spot a difference in the php environment :

```
ob_start();
phpinfo();
$phpInfo = ob_get_contents();
ob_get_clean();
Log::info("PHP INFO REPORT");
Log::info(print_r($phpInfo, true));
```

*First difference* : Visually when running "from within the app" I get an html formatted string (starting with `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ...`) whereas when running from command line with artisan, I only get the payload text (starting with `phpinfo()` ).

*Other differences* : System is not the same, `Server API => FPM/FastCGI` from within the app whereas it is `Command Line Interface` when launched from command line, `Loaded Configuration File` is also different.

cgi, fastcgi and fpm are missing when launched from command line

There are many other differences, I don't know which one I should stress here since the curl section is identical.

**Edit : trying curl from command line**

I tried to connect to the remote host with `curl -v re.mov.ed.ip:xyz` and got

```
Rebuilt URL to: re.mov.ed.ip:xyz/
Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
Trying re.mov.ed.ip...
connect to re.mov.ed.ip port xyz failed: Connexion refusée
Failed to connect to re.mov.ed.ip port xyz: Connexion refusée
Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to re.mov.ed.ip port xyz: Connexion refusée
```

How could it be that curl from command line does not find the address whereas it finds it from within the app ?

I don't know if it is relevant but I tried from the command line to `ssh-copy-id user@re.mov.ed.ip` and got `connection refused` and also `ssh user@re.mov.ed.ip` did fail  (port 22 was opened on the router). From my dev machine `ssh user@re.mov.ed.ip` did work.

**Edit : Bottom line**

It [looks like](http://community.ovh.com/t/connexion-refused-sur-curl-ainsi-que-en-shell-via-sftp-wget/21034/2) curl, wget or whatever tries to "ping" a url from command line is not allowed. Even php `@get_headers` will return false (ie error) from command line. **So my aim does not seem possible on (at least OVH) shared-hosting**.

Comment: what Laravel log says?

Comment: @phpdroid please see my last edit. In the beginning I replaced the exception stack trace with my own text because I did not find it useful. Now I see it could become handy!